# How can i apply LINQ query on nested collections by checking each collection is null or not using LINQ with asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can i access the nested collection by checking null or not using LINQ with asp.net c# ? As i am getting null exception when there is no mealPlan?

As i am getting null exception when there is no mealPlan?

### Part of code:-

```
var hotelRoomBooking = (from n in roomsPart.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        //where n.roomRates != null
                                        from rates in n.roomRates.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        //where rates.roomRate != null
                                        from roomR in rates.roomRate.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        //where roomR.mealPlans != null
                                        from mealP in roomR.mealPlans.mealPlan
                                        //where mealP.value != null
                                        from link in roomR.links.link
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            n.id,
                                            n.rooms.checkInDate,
                                            n.rooms.checkOutDate,`enter code here`
                                            n.rooms.totalCostOfRooms.totalCostInclusive.currency,
                                            roomR.averageNightlyRate.value,
                                            MealPlan = mealP.value != null ? mealP.value : string.Empty,
                                            n.stayDetails.noOfRooms,
                                            n.location.city,
                                            n.location.code
                                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you add your class structure for rooms, rates and mealplans?  I tried knocking up an example copy to work on your question but it's hard without knowing what criteria you're working against.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you'll get NullReferenceException. Try to use `join` if you want to exclude rows with null values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavel Bogdanov

Comment: Hi Pavel if possible can u provide some example url's for query on nested collection by checking nulls using Linq with C#.
Note:- Her i dont have a sope to apply joins also bcz as i am getting the data as JSON output from Orbitz API.